# How to get or unlock misc items if they exist?

Tags: chivalry-medieval-warfare

When choosing the weapon layout for a class there are 3 panes. 1 primary wep, 2 secondary wep, 3 misc.

On the 3rd misc item panel there are normally items like shields and smoke bombs.

With a crossbow man for example the third panel ONLY has a tower shield and a lot of locks.

Do these locks on the third panel mean items exist there that can be unlocked? and if so how do I unlock them?

(if my description is unclear let me know in comments and I will post a picture later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third panel represents special items and are not unlockable but can only be used under certain loadouts. For example an archer with a crossbow can use the pavise shield or extra ammo, however he can't pick bodkin arrows. In order to pick bodkin arrows the archer must switch out the crossbow with one of the arrow weapons (longbow, shortbow or warbow).

Some special items are not dependent on loadouts. For example men-at-arms can always use throwing knife regardless of their primary and secondary loadout.

Comment: ah that makes sense, the panel is static